# mark folder as binary in .gitattributes

Tags: git, github

I have to include some folder to a repository but I don't want my git to modify it's content (line endings etc)

I already have some files that are marked as binary files in .gitattributes i.e. images:

```
*.png binary
```

but this rule specifies certain category of files - png files, however I want to achieve something like that:

```
/folder_which_i_want_to_mark_as_binary binary
```

Comment: you can configure line endings depending on your system for unix based systems you do `git config --global core.autocrlf input` and for windows os `git config --global core.autocrlf true`. This should ensure correct line endings. What type of files will be stored in that folder of yours? Can't you do `folder/* binary` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix line endings you can apply following instructions

UNIX System

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Windows System

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Alternatively (in .gitattributes)

If you want to treat as binary everything in a particular folder, in `.gitattributes` you could add something like

```
*.sh text eol=lf
*.bat text eol=crlf
folder/* binary
```

Note: `folder` must be the name of your folder.

Comment: oh :-( after some tests I eventually realized that this does not work, all files within 'folder/' are still modified by git

Comment: Please don't use `core.autocrlf`.  Configure the line ending settings for everybody with `.gitattributes`.

Comment: @EdwardThomson thanks very much, I'll try this approach

Comment: @EdwardThomson thanks very much again, this approach does solve the issue, could you please create answer here

Comment: @EdwardThomson out of curiousity, why would you not use `core.autocrlf`?

Comment: @e.doroskevic It should be a setting of the repository.  Otherwise it relies on all developers to have it set the same across their machines to work correctly.  As soon as one person neglects to configure it - which of course they have to do manually - they're checking in things that disagree with somebody else's `core.autocrlf` setting. Checking it into the repo removes that manual step.

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky I would but I think that e.doroskevic's answer is quite good otherwise.

Comment: @EdwardThomson aah, he modified the answer, thanks very much for your effort!

Answer (score 25):

The currently accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741707/7200132) did not work for me. Possibly the behavior changed in recent versions of git. Quoting from the manual of [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes):

> The rules by which the pattern matches paths are the same as in .gitignore files (see gitignore[5]), with a few exceptions:
>
> - negative patterns are forbidden
> - patterns that match a directory do not recursively match paths inside that directory (so using the trailing-slash path/ syntax is pointless in an attributes file; use path/** instead)

Therefore, to treat a whole folder as binary, use the following syntax:

```
folder_which_i_want_to_mark_as_binary/** binary
```

Tested with git version 2.20.1.

Comment: Confirmed with git 2.25.2

Comment: Confirmed whit git version 2.10.0.windows.1

Comment: Winner! This should be the accepted answer. Did the behavior change at some point?