# keep unix line ending (LF) for certain files when checked out on a windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, git

I'm working in an windows/linux environment. Usually it doesn't matter if the files in windows are checked out with CRLF line ending and on linux with LF line endings.  But now I have project where a certain bunch of files in a specific directory needs to keep its unix LF ending even on windows.

e.g.

```
project/dir-a/file1
project/dir-a/file2
project/dir-b/file3
project/dir-b/file4
```

all files in dir-a can be either CRLF / or LF (depending if you check them out on linux or windows)  but for  "dir-b" all files **MUST** keep a unix LF on both platforms (windows and linux).

How can i achieve this? Is there a setting in git where i can set this for a directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `.gitattributes` file to the root of the project and add the below line into the file.

```
dir-b/* eol=lf
```

The above line declares all files in `dir-b` will have `LF` line endings on checkout. If you want specific files or extensions you can use something like:

```
foo eol=lf
*.c eol=lf
```

Comment: dir-b/* eol=lf  seems not work ? I try *.c eol=lf, it work.

Comment: How is your project structure? Are your files directly under the `dir-b` or in subfolders? If there are other subfolders, could you please try `dir-b/** eol=lf` or `dir-b/** text eol=lf`.

Comment: The dir-b/** eol=lf  worked. Also it may be the dir i test is not the directly dir or dir-b. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630133/3769941 here is the solution i find.